# select data from one column according to second column

Tags: php, sql

I think the title is not correct but here explain to you about the exact problem.
I have a table name 'testdata' in which four rows:-

[image: testdata image]

in this image have the structure of the table.

now my recruitment is:-

1. I want data according to bad no. in with a total of Daily Milk

ex.:

- b1 have total dailymilk is 15
- b2 have total dailymilk is 14
- b3 have total dailymilk is 18

i want something like:-

[image: expected screenshot]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: You can use this query "SELECT
  BaDaNo,
  (SELECT
     SUM(tmp_tbl.dailyMilk)
   FROM yourtable AS tmp_tbl
   WHERE tmp_tbl.BaDaNo = main_tbl.BaDaNo) AS dairy-milk
FROM yourtable AS main_tbl
GROUP BY main_tbl.dabNO
"

Answer (score 0):

you can use subquery and group by

```
 SELECT
  BaDaNo,
  (SELECT
     SUM(tmp_tbl.dailyMilk)
   FROM yourtable AS tmp_tbl
   WHERE tmp_tbl.BaDaNo = main_tbl.BaDaNo) AS dairy-milk
FROM yourtable AS main_tbl
GROUP BY main_tbl.dabNO
```

Answer (score -1):

use aggregate function

```
select BaDaNo,sum(dailyMilk) from yourtable

group by BaDaNo
```

Comment: @AmitKumar if it helps accept my answer, note please do not use image on problem description